# GLUI for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: user-interface, opengl, visual-studio-2012, glui

I am trying to draw an opengl window with some interactive text input boxes and the like to change the rendered image. I am trying to use GLUI to do this. I successfully created a sub-window in opengl window with glui. But when I am trying to add a listbox into this sub-window, it pops out the following errors.

glui32.lib(glui_edittext.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob
glui32.lib(glui_spinner.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob
glui32.lib(ALGEBRA3.OBJ) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __iob

I sought this online. It is possible that the glui32.lib that I am using is not compatible for visual studio 2012. So I tried to build glui's source code to get the .lib file. But I got the errors below:

```
e:\projectvis\glui compiling\glui-2.36\src\include\gl\glui.h(1718): error C2252: an explicit instantiation of a template can only occur at namespace scope
e:\projectvis\glui compiling\glui-2.36\src\include\gl\glui.h(1719): error C2252: an explicit instantiation of a template can only occur at namespace scope
e:\projectvis\glui compiling\glui-2.36\src\glui.cpp(186): error C2065: 'GLUT_DOUBLE' : undeclared identifier
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compiling GLUI library, VS2010 gives me a weird namespace error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910262/compiling-glui-library-vs2010-gives-me-a-weird-namespace-error)

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is just commenting the two lines of codes. Then you can get the glui32.lib file after building the solution. It works for me.